# CouchDB replication to cluster

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0

I'm trying to set up a single CouchDB node with a primary copy of a database and have it replicate (one way) to a three-node CouchDB cluster. I want to do this for HA and performance, the users would talk to the read-only cluster.

This setup doesn't seem to work, no matter what I try the replication always gets an authorization error. I'm 100% sure the password is correct. Indeed, I can't even seem to set up replication between one database and another within the cluster. All four nodes are running 2.3.0.

Is replication not compatible with clustering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does work, I found out what the issue was. I was specifying the clear-text admin password in the cluster configuration and each node was generating a hash for it with a different salt. The solution was to specify the same hashed value in the config file for all clustered nodes.